# Get acces to parent from composited object

Tags: c#, wpf, composition

So i have two clases with composition. First one is Image which represents node. Then another 4 images for each corner of parent image, which represent placeholders.

```
public class Node : Image 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public List<NodePlaceholder> PlaceholderList = new List<NodePlaceholder>();

    //creating Node Image, Creating 4 instances of NodePlaceholder for each corner and adding them to PlaceholderList

    TargetCanvas.Children.Add(this);
    foreach (var placeholder in PlaceholderList)
    {
         TargetCanvas.Children.Add(placeholder);
    }
 }


public class NodePlaceholder : Image
{
     this.MouseLeftButtonDown += NodePlaceholder_MouseLeftButtonDown;
}

void NodePlaceholder_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //how to get Parent Node ID?
}
```

Could you please advise me how to get acces to parent ID?

I have done this by passing creating inner property to represent parents ID and i pass it to NodePlaceholders constructor, but this creates redundancy (Same value in 5 different properties).
im sure there is more elegant way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a member object to the `NodePlaceholder` class to point back to the "Parent", and then be sure to assign it, e.g.:

```
foreach (var placeholder in PlaceholderList)
{
     TargetCanvas.Children.Add(placeholder);
     placeholder.Parent = this; //or this.ID, or whatever you need to access...
}
```

Comment: Then use a (new) `ParentImage` property that *isn't* read-only?